# How can Take permission using an alert Box at just destroy the application in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, editor, notepad

I just want to show an alert box at just killing the application in android.
It's like a Notepad application, if we simply kill the app (on clicking the close button) then we get an alert box asking for save changes.

I just want to add same thing in my application.I have tried **onBackPressed()** and its working fine on clicking on Back Button. But I need same thing on closing the application.

Answer (score 0):

There is now way to be sure if the app is being closed but you can place a check if the application is in foreground or not which is a better metric IMHO as this tells you when the user moved away from your application.

To check the [ProcessLifeCycleOwner](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner)  this will help you find state of process. You can check [this](https://github.com/jshvarts/AppLifecycleDemo) Github sample or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42576734/android-checking-whether-the-app-is-closed#:%7E:text=The%20%22onActivityDestroyed%22%20will%20get%20called,the%20app%20is%20being%20closed.) stackoverflow question in how to use it.